# resetting v-model of child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my parent component I have something similar to this,

```
<template>
    <ProductCounter v-model="formData.productCount" label="product count" />
</template>

<script setup>

const initialFormData = {
    productCount: null,
    firstname: '',
    surname: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    postcode: '',
    submittedOnce: false,
    errors: []
}

let formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });

const clearUI = () => {
    formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });
    triggerInlineForm.value = false;
}

</script>
```

My child component looks like this,

```
<template>
    <div class="form__row" @reset-counts="resetCount">
        <div class="counter__row">
            <label>{{ label }}</label>
            <div class="form__counter">
                <button class="form__button--decrease form__button--circle form__button--animate-scale" :disabled="value == 0 || props.disabled" @click.prevent="decreaseCount()">
                    <i>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="['fal', 'minus']" />
                    </i>
                </button>
                <input type="text" v-model="value" :disabled="props.disabled" @input="updateQty" placeholder="0"/>
                <button class="form__button--increase form__button--circle form__button--animate-scale" :disabled="props.disabled" @click.prevent="increaseCount()">
                    <i>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="['fal', 'plus']" />
                    </i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'resetCounts']);

const props = defineProps({
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false
    }
});

const value = ref(props.modelValue);

const updateQty = () => {
    emits('update:modelValue', value.value)
}

const increaseCount = () => {
    value.value++
    emits('update:modelValue', value.value)
}

const decreaseCount = () => {
    value.value--;
    emits('update:modelValue', value.value)
}

</script>
```

I would expect that when clearUI is fired from the parent, and formData gets reset the v-model of ProductCounter should reflect that go back to 0 but it does not, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[The link to live solution](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Please prepare minimum reproducible example the next time on https://play.vuejs.org/. And to your question:

You SHOULD NOT overwrite reactive variables in Vue please...

Just mutate them `Object.assign(formData, initialFormData)`:

Also don't dereference component properties: `const value = ref(props.modelValue)`. The properties lose their reactivity because you just a copy a primitive value.

The best way to create a `v-model` pattern is to use `computed` which you can manipulate directly in the template.

```
const value = computed({
  get(){
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(val){
    emits('update:modelValue', val);
  }
});
```

Also your count property should be a number, not a string (you get Vue warnings):

```
    modelValue: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
```

Also there's no need to update the prop on the `input` event, since you're already using `v-model` on the `<input>`. Also you should convert your input's model to a number:

```
 <input type="text" v-model.number="value" :disabled="props.disabled" placeholder="0"/>
```

So you have:
App.vue

```
<template>
    <p>
      <ProductCounter v-model="formData.productCount" label="product count" />
    </p>
    <button @click="clearUI">
      Clear
    </button>
    <div>
      {{ JSON.stringify(formData) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ProductCounter from './ProductCounter.vue'
import {reactive} from 'vue'
  
const initialFormData = {
    productCount: 0,
    firstname: '',
    surname: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    postcode: '',
    submittedOnce: false,
    errors: []
}

let formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });

const clearUI = () => {
    Object.assign(formData, initialFormData);
}

</script>
```

ProductCounter.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="form__row">
        <div class="counter__row">
            <label>{{ label }}</label>
            <div class="form__counter">
                <button :disabled="value == 0 || props.disabled" @click.prevent="value--">
                -
                </button>
                <input type="text" v-model.number="value" :disabled="props.disabled" placeholder="0"/>
                <button :disabled="props.disabled" @click.prevent="value++">
                 +
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {computed} from 'vue';
const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const props = defineProps({
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false
    }
});

const value = computed({
  get(){
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(val){
    emits('update:modelValue', val);
  }
});


</script>
```

Comment: Use `[short name](url)` markdown for URL shortening.

Answer (score 1):

When you override `formData` in `clearUI()`, you change the content of the variable:

```
let formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });

const clearUI = () => {
    formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });
}
```

However, this does not change the object that was bound to the template during component setup. You can fix this using `ref` and assigning to its value:

```
const formData = ref({ ...initialFormData });

const clearUI = () => {
    formData.value = { ...initialFormData };
}
```

or you can override the properties individually:

```
const formData = reactive({ ...initialFormData });

const clearUI = () => {
    Object.assign(formData, initialFormData);
}
```

---

A second problem is that you are setting the `value` in `ProductCounter` to the initial value of `props.modelValue`, but that is the literal value, not a reactive property. So when `props.modelValue` changes, `value` does not. To fix it, you can add a watcher:

```
const value = ref(props.modelValue);
watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  () => value.value = props.modelValue
)
```

Now `value` will be adjusted when `props.modelValue` changes.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)